# How to pull changes from github submodule branch "A" into parent module branch "B"

Tags: github, git-branch, git-submodules

I've made some changes in repository A, that are reflected in branch A. This repository A is a submodule for repository B. I want to reflect repository A's branch A changes in repository B's branch Y. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `X` be a branch of submodule `A` and `Y` be a branch of parent repository `B`.

Switch to `X` and change directory to the root of `B`. Running `git status` would show something like this:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   A (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then switch to `Y` and commit the changes:

```
git switch Y
git add A
git commit
```